# Longtable question

Tags: tables

I made this code but the words from the first column are superimposed:

```
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.4pt}
\begin{longtable}{cp{6.645em}cp{7.215em}p{6em}c}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{p{3.93em}}{Dataset} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.645em}}{SLAC} & MEME  & FEL   & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.215em}}{FUBAR} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{\begin{sideways}Basal\_40\end{sideways}}} & number of PSS & 0     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & 0 \\
\cmidrule{2-6}          & sites &       & 1, 6, 13, 85, 99, 149, 154, 200 & 154, 218 &  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{\begin{sideways}Strisores\_Aequorlitornithes\_40 \end{sideways}}} & number of PSS & 1     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} & 0 \\
\cmidrule{2-6}          & sites & 276   & 153, 154, 186, 238, 269, 276 & 49, 61, 123, 225, 238, 266, 268, 276 &  \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
    \midrule
  \label{table:Supplemental Table 9}%
\end{longtable}%
```

But I'm new to LaTeX and I wanted to make my table look like this other one I have in my docuemnt, but I don't know how. Can someone help me?

```
\small
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{c l c X X c}
    \toprule
    \thead{Dataset} &  & \thead{SLAC} & \thead{MEME}  & \thead{FEL}   & \thead{FUBAR} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Basal\_40}}} & number of PSS & 0     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & 0 \\
\cmidrule{2-6}          & sites &       & 1, 6, 13, 85, 99, 149, 154, 200 & 154, 218 &  \\
&   &   &                                        \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Strisores\_Aequorlitornithes\_40}}} & number of PSS & 1     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} & 0 \\
\cmidrule{2-6}          & sites & 276   & 153, 154, 186, 238, 269, 276 & 49, 61, 123, 225, 238, 266, 268, 276 &  \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Acanthisittidae Tyranni\_Passeri\_40}}} & number of PSS & 11     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{23} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{18} & 13 \\
\cmidrule{2-6}          & sites & 27, 43, 57, 58, 153, 157, 224, 231, 233, 234, 235   & 14, 27, 43, 44, 51, 56, 57, 58, 62, 67, 122, 130, 146, 153, 157, 224, 229, 231, 233, 235, 247, 265, 279 & 27, 43, 57, 58, 62, 67, 100, 130, 147, 153, 154, 156, 157, 224, 231, 233, 235, 265 &  27, 57, 58, 62, 122, 130, 153, 157, 179, 224, 231, 233, 235\\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Please be aware that combining `longtable` with `multirow` can easily lead to undesired overlapping of the (rotated) multirow text with the footer of a page. You might want to consider redesigning your longtable to avoid multirows.

Comment: your question is very hard to understand. You say you want the output to look like (the result of) your second block of code. What answer do you want other than using that code?

Comment: I made the code of the first one but I wanted to look similar to the second one

Comment: The problem here is that the table that I created superimposes some words, which didn't happen with the second table, that's why I wanted to make the first one look like the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Since you would need quite a lot of empty lines (=wasted space) in order to avoid the overlap of the rotated text, I also included an alternative layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
{
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.4pt}
\begin{longtable}{cp{6.645em}cp{7.215em}p{6em}c}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{p{3.93em}}{Dataset} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.645em}}{SLAC} & MEME  & FEL   & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.215em}}{FUBAR} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Basal\_40}}} & number of PSS & 0     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & 0 \\
\cmidrule{2-6}          & sites &       & 1, 6, 13, 85, 99, 149, 154, 200 & 154, 218 &  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{10}[4]{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Strisores\_Aequorlitornithes\_40}}} & number of PSS & 1     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} & 0 \\
\cmidrule{2-6}          & sites & 276   & 153, 154, 186, 238, 269, 276 & 49, 61, 123, 225, 238, 266, 268, 276 &  \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        
    \midrule
  \label{table:Supplemental Table 9}%
\end{longtable}%
}


\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{l c X X c}
\caption{caption} \label{table:Supplemental Table 9}\\
    \toprule
      & \thead{SLAC} & \thead{MEME}  & \thead{FEL}   & \thead{FUBAR} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{Dataset: Basal\_40}\\
       number of PSS & 0                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8}                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & 0 \\
       sites &       & 1, 6, 13, 85, 99, 149, 154, 200 & 154, 218                             &  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{Dataset: Strisores\_Aequorlitornithes\_40}\\
      number of PSS & 1                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6}                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} & 0 \\
      sites & 276   & 153, 154, 186, 238, 269, 276     & 49, 61, 123, 225, 238, 266, 268, 276 &  \\                        
    \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}%


\end{document}
```

---

Update in response to additional requirements mentioned in the comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
{
\small
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{c l c X X c}
    \toprule
    \thead{Dataset} & \thead{SLAC} & \thead{MEME}  & \thead{FEL}   & \thead{FUBAR} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Basal\_40}}} & number of PSS & 0     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & 0 \\
\cmidrule{2-6}          & sites &       & 1, 6, 13, 85, 99, 149, 154, 200 & 154, 218 &  \\
&   &   &                                        \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{12}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Strisores\_Aequorlitornithes\_40}}} & number of PSS & 1     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} & 0 \\
\cmidrule{2-6}          & sites & 276   & 153, 154, 186, 238, 269, 276 & 49, 61, 123, 225, 238, 266, 268, 276 &  \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\                   
    \midrule
  \label{table:Supplemental Table 9}%
\end{xltabular}%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very good! Is there any way to center SLAC, MEME, FUBAR and FEL with the numbers beneath it? I'd also like to put the whole table in the center of the page. Also, can you tell me which parameters should I change to make it wider and the columns more separated?

Comment: Which of the two versions do you refer to?

Comment: The first one. Even though it does have a lot of blank space, it looks more homogenous with the rest of my tabels. Addtitionally, when I put other rows with more numbers maybe it will look fuller.

Comment: @RaquelCardoso: I have updated my answer accordingly. I hope, this is now closer to the desired output.

Comment: That works very well, thank you. However, when I tried to continue my table with the next rows, these have more numbers and the table gets all unformatted

updated my question

Comment: Regarding your update: Probably `\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{c l X X X X}` works better for your table.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm so sorry to be bothering you again but do you know how to center this table? I tried \begin{center} and \centering in various places but it didn't work. I also wanna thank you again because u really helped with this table.

Comment: Since the xltabular is exactly as wide as the textwidth, it should already appear centered with respect to the textwidth. You can add the showframe package to your preamble in order to see a border that is drawn around the text block. Your table should now fit into there perfectly. Do you use a twoside documentclass? If so, the left and right margin will be different by design making the table appear off centered with respect to the whole page but centered with respect to the textwidth. I hope, I was able to help you with this issue. If you have more question, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I am doing a dissertation that is one-sided. This table is in the supplemental material and it's more to the left. It is easy to see compared to the other tables but also the caption is centered so I wonder why this table is more to the left. Can I change textwidth to something else that makes it centered?

Comment: I'm sorry but is there some way to push the table to the left so it is centered with the rest of my tables?

Comment: @RaquelCardoso: Did you use the second code I added? This should result in a table that is exactly as wide as the textwidth, so it should appear centered with respect to more narrow tables. Are your other tables wider than this one? If so, did you let them protrude into the left and right margin? Probably it would be better if you posted a new question focussing on this specific alignment problem. Please also include a MWE there that allows others to reproduce the output you get.